# How do I prove that an element is a within a set in Lean?

Tags: lean, set-theory

Given this code,

```
inductive Test : Type
| T1 | T2

example : Test.T1 ∈ { t: Test | t = Test.T1 } := begin
  sorry
end
```

How do I prove that `Test.T1 ∈ { t: Test | t = Test.T1 }` (which trivially seems to be the case)?
I tried the `intro` tactic but it did not work.

Comment: What you need to know is how things are defined under the hood. By *definition*, `x \in {a : X | P a}` means `P x`, so your goal is *definitionally* equal to `Test.T1 = Test.T1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rfl` should do the trick:

```
inductive Test : Type
| T1 | T2

example : Test.T1 ∈ { t: Test | t = Test.T1 } := rfl
```

Comment: This seems to work. Is there a way of solving it in tactics mode? `refl` does not seem to work.

Comment: @AndreaNardi The tactics `simp` and `exact rfl` and `split` seem to work.